# I've got to check palindrome using 2D array,i've used files but its not working

Tags: c++, c++11, palindrome

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int second();
main(){
    char myWord[5][20]={second()};
    int x;
    char c;
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("Palinput.txt");
    fout.open("Paloutput.txt");

    for(int row=0;row < 5;row++)
    {
        for(int col=0;col < 20 ;col++){
            cout<<myWord  [row][col];   

    }
int i, j, flag=0, n ='\0'-1;
for (i=0, j=n; i<j; i++,j--)

statement:
if (myWord[i]!=myWord[j])
{
    flag=0;
    break;
}
else
{
    flag=1;
}
if (flag)
cout<<myWord<<" pallindrome \n ";
else
cout<<myWord<<" not palindrome \n ";
        }

    return 0;
}
int second(){
    ofstream thefile("Palinput.txt");
    cout<<"Press enter after each word entered!\n";
    cout<<"Enter 5 string \n"<<endl;

    string txt;
int a;
for(a=0;a<=4;a++)
{
    cin>>txt;   
}
cout<<"Press ctrl+z to continue\n";
}
```

Comment: can you define what is not working more specifically

Comment: add some detail about your question. so that one could better understand.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a *terrible* way to ask a question.

Comment: My bad sorry,i think it is the comparing that is wrong,,,but i got no errors while compiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you properly indent things, many things become apparent, and it is much easier to track what is going on. see some of my comments i added to ur code below. but general overview is that you ask for inputs but never store them, simply overwrite them. then you try to check an empty char[][] to see if its a palindrome by comparing its rows to its columns. your code has significant problems. you should use a debugger like visual studio or gdb to step through your code to see what is happening. so you can understand what errors you made in the design of your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int second();
main()
{
    char myWord[5][20]={second()};//this isnt assigning to myWord
    int x;
    char c;
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("Palinput.txt");//opening file but not doing 
    fout.open("Paloutput.txt");//anything with it

    for(int row=0;row < 5;row++)
    {
        for(int col=0;col < 20 ;col++)
        {
            cout<<myWord  [row][col];//myWord has nothing in it

        }
        int i, j, flag=0, n ='\0'-1;
        for (i=0, j=n; i<j; i++,j--) //unused for loop

        statement: //unused label
        if (myWord[i]!=myWord[j])//how is a row=column? always true
        {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            flag=1;
        }
        if (flag)
            cout<<myWord<<" pallindrome \n ";
        else
            cout<<myWord<<" not palindrome \n ";
    }

    return 0;
}
int second()
{
    ofstream thefile("Palinput.txt"); //file never opened 
    cout<<"Press enter after each word entered!\n";
    cout<<"Enter 5 string \n"<<endl;

    string txt;
    int a;
    for(a=0;a<=4;a++)
    {
        cin>>txt; //simply overwriting a variable with new input
                  //without using the input
    }
    cout<<"Press ctrl+z to continue\n";
}
```